# OnClick Event Bootstrap Button

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am just trying to do a very basic task to make sure my Login button is firing before i start coding up the logic.

Here is my button :

```
<input type="submit" name="login-submit" runat="server" id="btnLogin" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In" onserverclick="btnLogin_Click"/>
```

Here is my code behind :

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        usernameLogin.Value = "Hello";
    }
```

Nothing is happening though, I don't know what I could be missing, I am guessing its a tag in the `input type`.... Any ideas?

It is not even hitting my breakpoint

Comment: Your code is working fine for me...

Comment: Which control id is "usernameLogin" ?

Comment: your code works fine for me also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<button>` tag instead of `<input>` , `OnServerClick` is a `HtmlButton` method